# Why can't I delete the current element when iterating over a list?

Tags: iteration, common-lisp, destruction

I want to iterate over a list, perform an action with the elements and based on some criteria, I want to get rid of the active element. However, when using the function below I end up in an infinite loop.

```
 (defun foo (list action test)
   (do ((elt (car list) (car list)))
       ((null list))
     (funcall action elt)
     (when (funcall test elt)
       (delete elt list))))

(setq list '(1 2 3 4))
(foo list #'pprint #'oddp)
-> infinite loop
```

Is it not possible as it points to itself? In the end, `elt` is `(car list)` of course.

Is this a correct assessment? And how could I solve this efficiently?

Comment: Random note for @quartus: I'd quickly give this question an upvote if it also included an expected behavior section -- what do you expect to have printed (and/or other side-effects), and what do you expect to be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can alter the state of your list while iterating over it. You will just have to use `rplacd` in addition to `delete`, and control the advancement along the list not in the iteration clause, but inside the do body:

```
 (defun nfoo (lst action test)
   (do* ((list (cons 1 lst))
         (elt (cadr list) (cadr list)))
        ((null (cdr list))
         (if (funcall test (car lst)) (cdr lst) lst))
     (funcall action elt)
     (if (funcall test elt)
       (rplacd list (delete elt (cddr list)))
       (setf list (cdr list)))))
```

You should call it via `copy-list` if you don't want it to destroy the argument list.

If you want to remove from your list not all elements equal to `elt` that passed the test, but rather all such that *will* pass the test, then the `delete` call will need to be passed the `test` function as the `:test` argument.

(**edit:**) and even much simpler and straightforward, like this (*non-destructive*) version:

```
(defun foo (list action test)
   (do* ((elt (car list) (car list)))
        ((null list))
     (funcall action elt)
     (if (funcall test elt)
       (setf list (delete elt list))
       (setf list (cdr list)))))
```

Comment: I see that your example works, but it _feels_ like `(setf list (delete elt list))` and `(setf list (cdr list))` are effectively doing the same thing twice.

Comment: This is broken if the intent is to modify the list. Variable `list` is a local function binding, and any `setf` only affect the inside of the function. Any references to this list from calling code will be still be pointing to some semi-random cons cell, since the original list will be destroyed by `delete`, and the function doesn't return the new list.

Comment: @Ramarren the *first version* will work if that is the intention, except removing the very first element of the list, if that passed the test. A `pop` call could do that, then. I should've renamed the second version back to just `foo`.

Comment: @quartus no, not the same thing. The second advances along the list as it is, the first advances along the list *and* removes all later occurrences of `elt` in it. (And of course not "twice" as their execution is mutually exclusive, as alternative cases of the `if` form.) The advancement must be done always, of course, to not get stuck on the same element.

Answer (score 3):

The loop is infinite since you are not iterating over anything, you apply the `action` repeatedly, but if it doesn't mutate the element, as `pprint` obviously doesn't, then if the `test` result is negative then it will remain so and the list wouldn't empty even if the deletion worked as you attempt it.

[DELETE](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm) is a destructive function. In Common Lisp destructive operations are allowed to *destroy* their argument. You are supposed to discard any references to the argument and use only the return value. After the operation is completed there are no guarantees about the state of the argument. In particular, there might be no effect as implementations are also allowed to act identically to a non-destructive counterpart, but usually the component parts of the sequence will be reassembled in some difficult to predict way. You are also destroying a literal in your example, which has undefined behaviour and it should be avoided.

It is generally best to treat lists in Common Lisp as immutable and destructive operations as a microoptization which should only be used when you are sure they won't break anything. For this problem you might want to iterate over the list using LOOP assembling the result list with conditional `COLLECT`. See the [LOOP chapter of PCL](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html).

Comment: I'd like to mark your answer as well, as it explains me the _nature_ of my function's behavior. Furthermore, in trying to simplify my piece of code in order to post it, I messed up a little, so you are right about the fact that I might end up in an infinite loop anyway.

Comment: and, do you really use destructive operations only for microoptimization? That's interesting to me. So you would use `(setq lst (delete elt lst))` instead of `(delete elt lst)`?

Comment: Yes. After (delete elt lst) you cannot use any existing references to lst, since it is in an unpredictable state. Only the return value is guaranteed to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit new to lisp, so perhaps I'm missing something in your question.  Still, I *think* I understand what you're asking, and I wonder why you're not using some existing structures for this... namely `remove-if-not` (or `remove-if` if I have things backwards) and `mapcar`...

```
(mapcar #'pprint (remove-if-not #'oddp '(1 2 3 4))
```

The above prints `1` and `3` (and returns `(nil nil)`, but presumably you can ignore that... or you could do a defun that does the above and ends with `(values)`).  (If you wanted the evens, change `remove-if-not` to `remove-if`.)

This strikes me as perhaps a more sensible way to go about things, unless you're doing this for pedagogical reasons or I'm missing something... either of which I admit is quite possible.  :)

P.S.  [Hyperspec info on `remove-if`, `remove-if-not`, etc.](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_removecm__elete-if-not.html)

Comment: the OP wanted to print out the first occurrences of the elements in the list which pass the test too, as well as all those that fail the test. Your approach won't print any elements passing the test. And you did get your `-if-not` backwards, coincidentally. :) Thanks for the MIT CLHS link, didn't even know it existed!

Comment: @WillNess: Ah well...  I think I'll leave this answer here in case it's useful to someone else anyway?  Hmm, I forget what the preferred behavior is.

Sure thing on the HyperSpec link.  Very very useful stuff -- though mostly I just get to it via random google searches.  :)

Comment: Good question, normally I would use such options for sure, but in the specific case I develop I have a something more sophisticated function, which actually could delete _several_ elements from the list during one iteration, depending on the test. As mentioned before the earlier example is _too_ much simplified.